# Which is the best way to find if a key exists in C# SortedList?

Tags: c#, .net, search, key, sortedlist

Which is the best way to find if a key exists in C# SortedList?

The question is quite clear, I have a SortedList represents an associated array. Both key and values are string. I'm thinking of scanning linear but binary search is faster coz it's 'Sorted'.

I wonder if there's a standard way to find the pair by key, like noted in MSDN or some where popular?

Comment: Off topic: I don't understand your usage of SortedList (list-type collection) for doing lookups.  If non-unique keys are requirement, have you investigated Lookup class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: just a habit, i don't know why i like SortedList than other Dictioanry... generic... etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.containskey.aspx) is the best way to find out if a key exists. It is already optimized, there is no need for you to make a custom search algorithm:

> "This method uses a binary search algorithm; therefore, this
>   method is an O(log n) operation, where n is Count."

Comment: sounds clearer than 'Contains', coz 'Contains' is quite confusing "key or value?". although as i've just read in msdn, they behave exactly the same :) tks :)